# Excel formula to separate " + " of two numbers in a cell

Tags: excel, concatenation, formula

If I in cell A1 have the formula:

```
=100+1250
```

(which equals 1350)

Is there a good way to get value 100 in A2 and 1250 in A3 with a formula? Something like; "Take value before character `+` in cell A2 and take value after character `+` in cell A3 .

Answer (score 2):

In Excel 2013 and later you can use the `FORMULATEXT` function and parse it any number of ways.

In Excel 2010 and earlier, you have to use VBA.  There's not a front-line function that can return the text of a formula in a cell.

Something like

```
Dim formula As String
formula = Range("A1").Formula
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use Find/Replace (what: `=`, with: nothing) then:

in A2: `=LEFT(A1,FIND("+",A1)-1)`

in A3: `=MID(A1,FIND("+",A1)+1,LEN(A1))`

Select/Copy/Paste/Special the results over the top and delete Row1 (or just A1).